# Laravel form validation - validating against 2 data columns

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel

I have a database table that tracks and email address and a client id. The rule is that and email can only belong to one client id. An example would be that I could add, email@domian.com and the client_id 20 but I would not be able to save that again, and this is where the form validation comes in,

I have the following validation rules in my controller,

```
$data = Input::all();
        $client_id = Input::get('client_id');

        $validation = Validator::make(
            array('email' => Input::get('email')),
            array('email' => 'required|email|unique:emails, email, NULL, client_id, $client_id')
        );

        if($validation->fails()) {

            return Response::json($validation->messages(), 400);

        } else {

        }
```

Basically I am saying that the email should be a valid email and it should be unique against all the other emails adress that have the same client id.

However I get a PHP error back,

> Undefined offset: 1

The POST that I am sending looks like this,

```
client_id: "16"  
email: "simon@simonainley.info"
involved: 1
project_id: "64"
visible: true
```

Comment: Try the validation rule without spaces after the comma: `required|email|unique:emails,email,NULL,client_id,$client_id` Also with single quotes `$client_id` won't be evaluated. Use double quotes or concatenate the string with the variable.